# Access modifier vs classes as thread boundary

Tags: c++, multithreading

I came to an interesting discussion in the office today. Let's say we have a class that should provide an interface to access some worker thread and give it some work (the actual thing is a bit more elaborated, but I don't think the details are relevant).

One approach would be having a class like:

```
class Manager
{
  public:
  void A(Work some_work) 
  {
    //Synchronization mechanism
    A_worker(some_work);
  }
  private:
  A_worker(Work some_work);
}
```

It can be argued that we are mixing methods running in different threads within the same class, but the user of the class will never land into a race condition.

Another approach would be:

```
class Manager
{
  public:
  void A(Work some_work) 
  {
    //Synchronization mechanism
    Manager_worker_pointer->InjectWork(some_work);
  }
  private:
  ManagerWorker* Manager_worker_pointer;
}

class ManagerWorker
{
   public:
   void InjectWork(Work some_work);
}
```

It can be argued that ManagerWorker provides a public interface that could lead to race conditions, but we are not mixing methods from the same class running in the same thread. Also this class shouldn't be exposed in the component we are developing (or maybe being a private class definition).

One of the solutions was implemented by me, and then my manager complained that the very right solution was the other one. I am not telling which one in order not to introduce bias in the answers.

What would be the best approach when implementing such interface? First one or second one? Why?

EDIT. I see the question was marked as opinion based. Well, that this question is opinion based would be a valid answer. So there is no reason to prefer one approach over the other.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is  "mixing methods running in different threads within the same class" a bad thing?

Comment: Personally I would use the solution that is race condition free instead of having to remember a gotcha.

Comment: @AbhishekPatel That's part of the question :) But it was argued that mixing methods from the same class running within same thread makes the class harder to maintain and understand.

Comment: @Abhishek Patel It can easily lead to mixing different concerns in one class which is rarely a good idea. I don't see how one solution leads to a race condition while the other one doesn't (you have a private member of the worker class - if you get a race condition with one approach you should have it with the other as well). Consumer-producer is well understood (it's sad that c++ still doesn't offer some high level structures for it in the standard library) and you really want to have separate class for both.

Comment: @Voo so if you want to execute an object's method on another thread, rather than creating thread in the method, call the method from a different thread?

Comment: @Abhishek I don't understand your question. The point is if you have code that *products* data and code that *consumes* data, those two things sounds like different things that should be clearly separated.

Comment: @Voo In the case I am talking about, all the code consumes data. Just part of it (mainly syncronization/construction/destruction stuff) runs in one thread, and the rest in another one.

Comment: @sapito Not enough information to judge, but generally it's rare that smaller classes are a problem - usually it's the other way around. Both solutions are suspect to race conditions in the same way, the argument that just because your private member has a public method makes it somehow racier doesn't compute.

Comment: @Voo But what second solution is proposing is having the synchronized interface in one class and the actual worker in another class. Wouldn't make sense to have synchronization+worker in the same class?